# Return all rows containing specific value in json array

Tags: sql-server, json

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Journals](
    [Id] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [CorrelationId] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [Version] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Data] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Updated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Journals] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Journals] ADD  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [Created]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Journals] ADD  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [Updated]
GO
```

One row could look like this:

```
Id: 1833eac9-3ea7-4613-be26-af3f7589d6f0
CorrelationId: 0HLNKM700ILBN:00000001
Version: 1
Type: Notification
Data: [{"type": "Event_Received","timeStamp": "2019-06-24T12:47:54.3960942Z","data": {"version": 1,"notificationName": "My Notification","receiverName": "John Doe","receiverUserIdentifier": "123456789","receiverEmail": "john.doe@example.org","senderName": "Some Sender","senderEmail": "someone@example.org","contentSubject": "This is my subject","contentBody": "And this is my body","attachmentNames": []},"sensitive": true}, {"type": "Event_ValidationSucceded","timeStamp": "2019-06-24T12:47:54.4167034Z","data": "{}","sensitive": false}, {"type": "Event_PublishStart","timeStamp": "2019-06-24T12:47:54.4691455Z","data": "{}","sensitive": false}, {"type": "Event_PublishSucceeded","timeStamp": "2019-06-24T12:47:54.4740542Z","data": "{}","sensitive": true}]
Created: 2019-06-19 12:29:20.8100000
Updated: 2019-06-19 12:30:51.1123311
```

I want to fetch all the Ids from the rows that contains array entries where Sensitive = true

So I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Journals journals
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(journals.Data)
WITH (JournalType nvarchar(255) '$.type', Sensitive bit '$.sensitive') as jsonValues
WHERE Sensitive = 1
```

This works but I get duplicate ids back (since the array contains more than one item where Sensitive = true).

How can I limit the query so that I don't receive duplicate Ids when the array contains more than one item where Sensitive = true?

Wanted output:

```
1833eac9-3ea7-4613-be26-af3f7589d6f0
```

Actual output:

```
1833eac9-3ea7-4613-be26-af3f7589d6f0
1833eac9-3ea7-4613-be26-af3f7589d6f0
```

I guess that I could add a DISTINCT to SELECT DISTINCT Id but that feels like cheating, or? :D

Comment: As a side note: if you keys are always UUIDs then using the `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` type instead of `[N][VAR]CHAR` will be more efficient. You'll use 72 bytes/value with 'NVARCHAR' instead of 16 with `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` and as it is your clustering key you'll spend that extra 56 bytes per row again in *every* non-clustered index defined on that table.

Comment: Nice, thank you, will fix right away :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You could opt to use `TOP(1)` in the `CROSS APPLY`**

```
SELECT Id
FROM Journals journals
CROSS APPLY 
(
SELECT TOP(1) Sensitive
FROM OPENJSON(journals.Data)
WITH (JournalType nvarchar(255) '$.type', Sensitive bit '$.sensitive')
WHERE Sensitive = 1
) as jsonValues;
```

**Or, as you mentioned `DISTINCT`**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id
FROM Journals journals
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(journals.Data)
WITH (JournalType nvarchar(255) '$.type', Sensitive bit '$.sensitive') as jsonValues
WHERE Sensitive = 1;
```

---

**Main difference between the two**

**When using the `TOP(1)` the values will be filtered and the top operator will be applied earlier in the execution plan**

[image]

**When using the `DISTINCT` solution, the filtering and grouping is only done after the JSON function is *(cross)* applied**

[image]

Which is why I would opt for the `TOP(1)` + `CROSS APPLY` solution.

---

As a side note, storing unique identifiers as `nvarchar()` is not ideal, especially when using a huge data type like `nvarchar(450)`. Consider using the minimal or close to the minimal amount of space needed in your column datatypes & using the `uniqueidentifier` datatype.

Comment: Really great answer, thank you!

Comment: @JOSEFtw No problem, happy to help :)!